# Active items in vertical menu

Tags: html, css, menu

There is vertical menu defined in style.css. I would like to activate the style "active" once the user has selected particular menu item. I cannot put `class="active"` inside the `<a`, because then the item will be always active. What I want is to apply style "active" once the item has been selected.

```
<ul id = "vertmenu">
    <li>
        <img style='float: left; margin-right: 5px;' src='images/mailIcon.png'/>
        <a href="#" onclick="change_page('tables/111.php', 'col2')"><span>111</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img style='float: left; margin-right: 5px;' src='images/calendarIcon.png'/>
        <a href="#" onclick="change_page('tables/222.php', 'col2')"><span>222</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img style='float: left; margin-right: 5px;' src='images/contactsIcon.png'/>
        <a href="#" onclick="change_page('tables/333.php', 'col2')"><span>333</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <img style='float: left; margin-right: 5px;' src='images/contactsIcon.png'/>
        <a href="#" onclick="change_page('tables/444.php', 'col2')"><span>444</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- --------- CSS ----------- -->
    ul#vertmenu li a.active, ul#vertmenu li a.focus {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFCF8B;
        outline-style: none;
        color: #AA0000;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
        }

    #vertmenu .active{
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFCF8B;
    outline-style: none;
    color: #AA0000;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

UPDATE 2;

```
<head>
            <script>  
 var links = document.getElementById("vertmenu").getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    links[i].onclick = function(event){
        for(var j = 0; j < links.length; j++){
            links[j].classList.remove('active');
        }
        event.target.parentNode.classList.add('active');
        change_page('tables/'+event.target.innerHTML+'.php','col2');
        return false;
    };
}​

            </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

how about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/49M49/

```
var links = document.getElementById("vertmenu").getElementsByTagName("a");

for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++){
    links[i].onclick = function(event){
        for(var j = 0; j < links.length; j++){
            links[j].classList.remove('active');
        }
        event.target.parentNode.classList.add('active');
        change_page('tables/'+event.target.innerHTML+'.php','col2');
        return false;
    };
}​
```

or in jQuery:

```
$("#vertmenu a").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $("#vertmenu a").removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        change_page('tables/'+$(this).find("span")[0].text()+'.php','col2');
    });
});
```

Comment: Please look at my update. I combined your code with my code. Now the style is changed once I select menu icon. BUT, the content of DIV container does not change any more. As you may see, I'm calling onclick="change_page('tables/333.php', 'col2')".

Comment: you need to move the change_page into the event handler - I've updated my example.

Comment: I believe your code should work. Please take a look at the update in my post. I just copied your first code and putted it inside <script> tags. It does not work...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/99WJ2/1/ it does work ^^ - I think you need to use `$(document).ready(function(){  <insert code here>  });`

Answer (score 0):

```
ul#vertmenu li a:active
{
    /*Styling*/
}
```

Comment: If you look at my sample code, you will find this part of the code in CSS stylesheet. But for some reason the style "active" is not applied to menu icons when I press on them.

Comment: I think that's because you're using 'a.active' instead of 'a:active'.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I've just tested this in jsFiddle and items do not remain highlighted. I'd go with Shibin's solution.